# Knockout Js Array.removeAll() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
var x=ko.observableArray([....]);
x.removeAll();
```

Situation is 'x' is holding the selected values from dropdowns which are dynamically generated using knockout. I want to clear all the selections made by the user.

The above code is not working in my situation, so i have to 'undefine' each element in the array using a for loop - which is a very bad way(i feel). i want to know if there any better way of doing this?

I also tried this:

```
x([]);
```

Which didn't work either.

My code Looks something like this

```
 var data_Main = [
{[a,b,c] },{[d,e,f]},{[g,h,i]}
 ];
 var selectedKoArray= ko.observableArray([]);
 var Lst=ko.observableArray([
 {Txt: 'aaa', Val: 'a'},
 {Txt: 'bbb', Val: 'b'},
 {Txt: 'ccc', Val: 'c'}
 ]);

 var dataArray = ko.observableArray([Lst:Lst(), Lst:Lst1(), Lst:Lst2()]);

 var selectedHFilters = ko.observableArray([]);

 for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (selectedKoArray[i])
                        selectedKoArray[i] = undefined;
                }

-----------------------------------------------------HTML-------------------------------
<div data-bind="foreach:dataArrayKO ">
<select  class="select2-offscreen filter-select" data-bind="options:Lst, optionsText: 'Txt', optionsValue: 'Val', optionsCaption: '-Select-', value:$root.selectedHFilters[$index()]"></select>             
</div>
```

Comment: [removeAll() maybe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638507/how-to-clear-contents-of-an-observablearray-that-was-populated-from-previous-vis)

Comment: i tried both 'remove' and 'removeAll'

Comment: Can you provide enough (*minimal*) HTML and JavaScript to reproduce the problem in your question?

Comment: In the script which you're developing, could you add `console.log(typeof x);` to ensure that `x` *is* an observableArray at the point where you're calling `removeAll`? Perhaps it gets modified between the declaration and the call to `removeAll`.   Also, how do you know that it's not working? Are there still elements in the observable array or is there an exception?

Comment: @David i know you need that but it is very difficult to create all the same environment

Comment: @awj I traced each and every step in debugger... still can't find any error.

Comment: As a last resort, you can always just re-initialise the observable: `x = ko.observableArray([...]);`

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid Javascript and will error, which may be the root of your problem:

```
var dataArray = ko.observableArray([Lst:Lst(), Lst:Lst1(), Lst:Lst2()]);
```

I suspect you wanted something like this (though Lst(), Lst1() and Lst2() are not defined in the code you've supplied, again this will error).

```
var dataArray = ko.observableArray([Lst.Lst(), Lst.Lst1(), Lst.Lst2()]);
```

The KO code for removing elements you have supplied is fine.

Comment: Lst1 and Lst2 are not defined. Hit F12 and look at console... you are almost certainly getting errors.